# trigger that save every insert ot update to an table as a log

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table called customer

```
id   share
1      5
2      2
3      4
```

and the id here is primary number

and have this table called detail

where  id is not primary key and save every thing either insert or update

```
id   share     date
1     2        22/4/2014
2     1        23/4/2014
1     2        24/42014
3     2        25/4/2014
1     1        26/4/2014
2     1        27/4/2014
```

and so on

when i want to insert new id should save to another table id and share value
and when i want to update existing value it must insert to detail table what is value updated not the total

it may done by linked it to c# or other shell >>> but here as individual can we do this,,, please help

Comment: It seems that you want a trigger in the database.  You should start with the documentation on triggers:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Comment: do you want to track inserts/updates on the customer table OR the detail table?

Comment: track customer table please mr @brian demilia

Comment: track customer table please mr @brian demilia into detail table

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

**Fiddle demonstration:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35020/1/0

Consider the following series of DDL/DML statements:
(the creation of the triggers and of the detail table is what's important to you, as your customer table already exists)

```
delimiter //

create table customer
(
 id int,
 share int,
 constraint id_pk primary key (id)
)//

insert into customer values
(1, 5),
(2, 2),
(3, 4)//

create table detail
(
 log_id int not null auto_increment,
 log_ts timestamp, customer_id int,
 customer_share int,
 action varchar(10),
   constraint log_id_pk primary key (log_id)
)//

create trigger customer_insert_log before insert on customer
    for each row begin
        insert into detail (log_ts, customer_id, customer_share, action)
             values (current_timestamp, new.id, new.share, 'INSERT');
end
//

create trigger customer_update_log before update on customer
    for each row begin
        insert into detail (log_ts, customer_id, customer_share, action)
             values (current_timestamp, new.id, new.share, 'UPDATE');
end
//

insert into customer values (4, 9),
                            (5, 3),
                            (6, 9)//

update customer set share = 3 where id = 2//

delimiter ;
```

If you then run a select statement against the detail table (select * from detail), you get:

```
| LOG_ID |                        LOG_TS | CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_SHARE | ACTION |
|--------|-------------------------------|-------------|----------------|--------|
|      1 | August, 23 2014 17:44:43+0000 |           4 |              9 | INSERT |
|      2 | August, 23 2014 17:44:43+0000 |           5 |              3 | INSERT |
|      3 | August, 23 2014 17:44:43+0000 |           6 |              9 | INSERT |
|      4 | August, 23 2014 17:44:43+0000 |           2 |              3 | UPDATE |
```

This detail table records the time something was done, what was done (insert or update) and what new values got inserted into (or updated to become) at that time.

Notice how the detail table shows the 3 rows I inserted, and also captures the UPDATE I ran at the end.

A key thing to note is that you have to change the delimiter to something other than a semicolon when you create the trigger, I used a double slash (//).

To set the delimitter to a double slash, you use:

```
delimiter //
```

Then after you create the trigger you can set it back to a semicolon -

```
delimiter ;
```

Comment: thanx very much ... i will try it and see if it compatible with my other triger

Comment: what is delimateer please

Comment: in general: what separates one thing from another, in this context: what separates one sql statement from the next sql statement

Comment: By default it is a semicolon ";" but because you also need to separate actions in the trigger with a semicolon, you have to set the delimitter for sql statements to something other than a semicolon so that the database doesn't get confused and think you're skipping on to another sql statement. You can then change it back after you are done creating the trigger.

Comment: i make copy past to ur code but it doesnot work.how come.. give more than error

Comment: @MsaMan probably because you didn't set the delimiter to // as shown. The first line of the code is: "delimiter //" (without quotes). That must be run first.

Answer (score 0):

i make copy past to ur code but it doesnot work
how come

these errors is appear

---

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'auto_increment'.
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
Incorrect syntax near '/'.

Comment: It definitely doesn't think the delimitter is // which means you didn't set it to // using "delimiter //" That has to be run first.